# incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') with an expression of type 'UIView *'

Tags: iphone, uitableview, tableview, xcode4.5, accessoryview

I got a problem with my tableview.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

UITableViewCell *tableCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
BOOL isSelected = (tableCell.accessoryView = [[ UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark-hvid"]]);

if (isSelected) {

    tableCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

}
else {

    tableCell.accessoryView = [[ UIImageView alloc ]

                               initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark-hvid"]];
}

}
```

The problem is i cant define BOOL isSelected as an assessoryView (image).

If any body knows the answer please help me!

- Mikkel V (sry my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

In this statement:

```
BOOL isSelected = (tableCell.accessoryView = [[ UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark-hvid"]]);
```

The *type* of `(tableCell.accessoryView = ...` is `UIView *` and that is what the compiler is complaining about.  In order to convert it into a `BOOL`, do this:

```
BOOL isSelected = (tableCell.accessoryView = [[ UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark-hvid"]]) != nil;
```

(Note the comparison with `nil`, which results in a boolean condition).

However all your code looks somewhat *dodgy*, as I would expect the `alloc/init` to always succeed and therefore `isSelected` to be always `YES`.